# writing functions as a power series

Tags: functions, soft-question, power-series, taylor-expansion

An important concept discussed in introductory calculus is that we are able to express some functions using a power series representation.

Is possible to extend this statement and say that we are able to write ALL functions using the power series representation?

Comment: "ALL" functions? Like the absolute value function, the floor function, the prime counting function, the Dirichlet function ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Inside the radius of convergence of a power series, the function to which it converges is infinitely differentiable. Not all functions are infinitely differentiable.

Comment: This answer is perfect. +1

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to @jawheele's response, even if a given function is infinitely differentiable, it's not guaranteed to have a power series representation centered on a given point. For instance, the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} & \text{ if }x\neq 0\\
0 & \text{ if }x=0
\end{cases}$$

satisfies $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n\geq 0$, so a power series representation for $f$ centered at $0$, if it exists, will (necessarily) be

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}(x-0)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}0=0$$

This contradicts the fact that $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ for all $x\neq 0$, so it cannot have a power series representation around $0$.

If you're wondering why the power series of $f$ around $0$ must be the one above, I'd recommend reading about the theory of Taylor series.

Comment: +1. Minor typo: I think you wanted to say $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n \geq 0$.

Comment: @jawheele that's embarrassing. Thank you for catching that!